I am having trouble creating a sub folder using dependency injection for User workorder's when the user submits the order in laravel 11
I am new to laravel and having trouble figuring out the path and creating a sub folder for workorders when the user submits the order in laravel 11.
I have a create user folder on registration in storage-> private-> user_files
This is in my registered userController to create folder. Private2 is my config/filesystems.php file
         $folderName =  $user->id . '_' . $user->name;
       
         $file_folder_path = $folderName;
         $userDirectory = $file_folder_path;
         Storage::disk('private2')->makeDirectory($userDirectory );
    
         $user->save();

Here is a diagram
1.) New user folder created on registration (works)2.)   ->orders folder created on order submit form(sub folder for user folder) for new orders(trying to figure out how to reference the user folder that is created with $user->id . '_' . $user->name;)
Thanks
Tried creating new driver in filesystem. Tried adding {user_id}_{user_name} to 'root' => storage_path('app/private/user_files'),

So, what issue are you currently facing? Does your code not work? Does it throw an error? What is the expected outcome? Could you elaborate?

First thing I see is that 2 of the 3 variables you create are unnecessary, $file_folder_path and $userDirectory hold the exact same value as $folderName and are redundant. Other than that I think $folderName needs a slash before it, so the directory is actually created in your private2 disk.
